# How to inherit protected static member in c++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have a Class.h, where i have this class:

```
class A {
protected:
    static int abc;
...

class B : public A {
...
}
```

Where i try to define in Class.cpp abc as member of B like this:

```
int B::abc = 123;
```

I have this error: ISO C++ does not permit 'A::sabc' to be defined as 'B::abc'
How can i make this work?

Comment: _"How can i make this work?"_ You can't.

Comment: Then what should i do?

Comment: Provide a `static int& abc() { return A::abc; }` function in class `B`.

Comment: Is the goal to let `B` have it's own separate static variable? In that case you need to define it in the definition for `B`.

Comment: *"How can i make this work?"* -- how do you define "work"? Your compiler rejected your code because its literal meaning is nonsensical. In the absence of words describing the goal, we're left to infer from non-functioning code, which is sketchy at best. What do you intend this code to accomplish? (What is your understanding of what this code says to do?)

Comment: XY problem, if ever there was one

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
int A::abc = 123;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a specific issue once. Here is a similar way I solved my problem.

```
#include <iostream>

// Class A
class A {
    private:
        static int staticValue;
    public:
        A();
        ~A();

        virtual int getStaticValue();
};

int A::staticValue = 1;

A::A() {}
A::~A() {}

int A::getStaticValue() {
    return staticValue;
}

// Class B
class B : public A {
        private:
            static int staticValue;
        public:
            B();
            ~B();
        
            virtual int getStaticValue();
};

int B::staticValue = 2;

B::B() {}
B::~B() {}

int B::getStaticValue() {
    return staticValue;
}

int main() {
    A a = A();
    B b = B();

    std::cout << a.getStaticValue() << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.getStaticValue() << std::endl;
}
```